# Android Volley Request - within request populating custom class not working

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I've got an Activity consisting of a buch of TextViews (fourteen) and two Buttons.
I have created a custom class named `Lesson`, wich basically has a constructor and getter methods for its variables.
Now, inside my `onCreate()` in my Activity I am calling two functions: 1.) `populateLessonDetails(myURL)` and 2.) `populateLessonTextViews()`.

I have created a `private Lesson mLesson;` variable inside my Activity, above all the `@Overrides`, because I'm trying to use this variable to populate it later on.

So, `populateLessonDetails(myURL)` is basically making a `JsonArrayRequest`, getting all the data from the JSON inside the `onResponse()`, saving it to `String` variables still inside the `onResponse()` and then, still inside the `onResponse()` I am trying to populate the `mLesson` variable, by calling 
`mLesson = new Lesson(mName, mRoom, mExtra, mAddress, mPC, mCity, mStart, mDate, mRID, mMaxAtt, mCurrentAtt);` - the variables used within the constructor are the `String` variables containing the JSON data.

I `Log.i()` the JSON data as well as the `mLesson` variables via its getter methods, and the data is there. Everything is fine.

Now, my `populateLessonDetails()` ends. 
It returns to the `onCreate()` and continues with the next line of code, wich would be calling `populateLessonTextViews()`.
This is where things went south... 
As soon as the function is called I try to get the information stored inside `mLesson` via its getter methods to set it to the `TextViews` like so:

```
    //Lesson Name Big
    TextView lessonNameTextBig = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_activelesson_name_big);
    lessonNameTextBig.setText(mLesson.getLessonName());
```

This is the proper way to do it, I've done it a bunch of times already, but my App crashes at the second line.

I have debugged it and I have noticed that `mLesson` is empty. My guess would be that me populating it inside the `onResponse()` of the `JsonArrayRequest`, which is inside the `populateLessonDetails()` is only valid for this particular function, the scope of the variable `mLesson` ends when the function returns to the `onCreate()` and the `mLesson` variable is empty again since it died with the function.

Now how can I fix this? Do I have to set `mLesson` as a parameter  for the `populateLessonDetails()` and then also return it (currently the populate functions are `void`) ? Then save the return value into another variable of type Lesson and set this new variable as a parameter for the `populateLessonTextViews()` ?? I've tried a couple of those things but they didn't work, but maybe its just me not doing it right.

This is what my code looks like (the important part):

```
public class ActiveLesson extends AppCompatActivity {
// there are also some other variables up here 
private Lesson mLesson;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_active_lesson);
    requestQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    mDatum = extras.getString("datum");
    mRID = extras.getString("rid");
    mVon = extras.getString("von");

    myActiveLessonURLFiltered += "datum="+mDatum+"&rid="+mRID+"&von="+mVon;

    populateLessonDetails(myActiveLessonURLFiltered);
    populateLessonTextViews();

}

private void populateLessonDetails(String myActiveLessonURLFiltered) {

    JsonArrayRequest lessonJAR = new JsonArrayRequest(myActiveLessonURLFiltered, 
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response){
            try{
                for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String mName = jsonObject.getString("Name");
                    String mRoom = jsonObject.getString("Raum");
                    String mExtra = jsonObject.getString("Zusatz");
                    String mAdresse = jsonObject.getString("Address");
                    String mPC = jsonObject.getString("PLZ");
                    String mCity = jsonObject.getString("City");
                    String mMaxAtt = jsonObject.getString("maxAnz");
                    String mCurrentAtt = jsonObject.getString("belegtAnz");

                    if(mExtra.length()==0 || mExtra == "null")
                        mExtra="";
                    if(mRoom.length()==0 || mRoom == "null")
                        mRoom="";
                    else
                        mRoom="Room: "+mRoom;

                    if(mName.length()==0 || mName == "null")
                        mName="";

                    mLesson = new Lesson(mName, mRoom, mExtra, mAdresse, 
                  mPC, mCity, mVon, mDatum, mRID, mMaxAtt, mCurrentAtt);

                    Log.i("mmLesson"," Lesson with new =  "+ mLesson.getLessonName() 
              +" "+mLesson.getLessonCity());

                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(ActiveLesson.this, "No Lessons Available", 
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }

    };
    requestQ.add(lessonJAR);
}

private void populateLessonTextViews(Lesson mLesson) {

    //Lesson Name Big
    TextView lessonNameTextBig = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_activelesson_name_big);
    lessonNameTextBig.setText(mLesson.getLessonName());

    // there are others lines of code like these two, 
    //  but I've left them out, since they are all the same
}
```

If some could help me out I would appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: I guess what I could do, would be to define all the `TextViews` inside the `onCreate()` and then set their content directly inside the `onResponse()` via `setText()` - so I would skip the need for the `mLesson` variable of type `Lesson` - but thats not how I really imagined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onResponse()` method is a callback that is called later when the network request returned a value. The server does not respond with any delay. This means the `populateLessonDetails(..)` method get called from onCreate triggers an network request and return immedietly to the `onCreate()` call of this function and steps forward. 
You have to take this in consideration. The best way to do this, call inside the onResponse the `populateLessonTextViews()` method. Then you can be sure that the content has been loaded.

Comment: do you mean to say that I should make the JsonArrayRequest inside the `onCreate()` or do you mean that I should call the `populateLessonDetails()` again inside itself? .. or maybe you actually meant for me to call `populateLessonTextViews()` inside `populateLessonDetails()` ? I'm not quiet sure. Thank you

Comment: I got it, you meant for me to call `populateLessonTextViews` inside the `onResponse` which is inside the `populateLessonDetails()` instead of calling it in the `onCreate` - right? I just did that and it works !! Thank you very much !